# CollectionviewSource Filter with multiple lambda expression

Tags: c#, collectionviewsource

I am trying to create a CollectionViewSource based on the values in two different comboboxes, Company and DataType.  Both of these comboboxes include an option for "ALL".

I have created the `ICollecitonView` and filter as such:

```
public ICollectionView TranslationMappingsView { get; set; }
```

and in the connstuctor I have created the filter as such:

```
  TranslationMappingsView = new CollectionViewSource { Source = TranslationMappingModel.TranslationMappings }.View;
        TranslationMappingsView.Filter = (m => SelectedCompany == "ANY" || SelectedCompany == ((TranslationMapping)m).CompanyCode)
            && (m => SelectedDataType == "ANY" || SelectedDataType == ((TranslationMapping)m).TranslationType);
```

However, I get an error of `Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'lambda expression' and 'lambda expression'`

Is there a way to apply both of these conditions to the filter?

Comment: Instead of `(m => expr1) && (m => expr2)`, why don't you simply do `(m=> expr1 && expr2)`?

Comment: @elgonzo thank you that did the trick